# Spark unzip and write CSV as parquet in executor

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My issue is that my CSV files come in ZIP `.csv.zip` format so I cannot just use Sparks `.csv` directly as I could with `.csv.gzip | .csv.gz`. Which means I need to decompress the file, read the contents (the files are quite big ~5gb) and write them as parquet files.

My approach is as such:

```
String paths = "s3a://...,s3a://...,...";
JavaRDD<Tuple2<String, PortableDataStream>> zipRDD = context.binaryFiles(paths, sparkContext.context.defaultParallelism()).toJavaRDD();
JavaRDD<Tuple2<String, List<Row>>> filenameRowsRDD = zipRDD.flatMap(new ConvertLinesToRows());
```

The first `JavaRDD` returns a pair of `Filename, InputStream`. This is then passed to class `ConvertLinesToRows` which calls `ZipInputStream` reads the contents of CSV files and for each line creates a new spark `Row` and finally returning tuple pair of `Filename, List<Row>` where the list contains all lines from CSV converted to Row.

I now want to save each read CSV as `parquet` file.

```
filenameRowsRDD.foreach(tuple -> {
    SparkContext newContext = MySparkConfig.createNewContext();
    SparkSession newSpark = SparkSession.builder()
        .sparkContext(newContext)
        .getOrCreate();

    Dataset<Row> dataset = newSpark.createDataFrame(tuple._2, datasetSchema.value());
    dataset.write().parquet("s3a://...");
});
```

I recreate the SparkSession in my executor so to be able to use SparkSession.write.

The idea is that this will all run in an executor (I'm hoping). However with this approach, reading file is not an issue problem comes when executor wants to write this output file. Throwing exception for: `A master URL must be set in your configuration`.

This seems like I'm doing something anti-spark way. It also does not work. I have also tried broadcasting my `SparkSession` however that throws a NPE inside `SparkSession` before trying to write.

1. What would be the correct way to approach my problem here ?
2. What would be the spark way of doing this.

All of the above code in in my `main()` method. Am I correct in assuming that first `zipRDD` is run on `master` node and than the second `filenameRowsRDD` runs on executor nodes as well as the `.foreach`.

Comment: How do you submit your job ? And the spark way would be not using spark ;)

Comment: @Vincent Using AWS EMR which calls `spark-submit --master yarn ...`

Comment: Okay so you shouldn't create a sparkSession in a for loop, that's why it's asking for a spark master URL. GetOrCreate will only get the EMR SparkSession from your Main class.